# Can we add multiple pages in renderAsPdf in visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have single page pdf document from Visualforce page using renderAsPdf, can we add multiple pages in the pdf document?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate multiple paper pages out of one Visualforce page you could read up about CSS `page-break-before: always;`. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/194196/799 is a pretty decent example (shameless plug)

To generate 1 master PDF that combines content from multiple different Visualforce pages/components... Read up about [apex:include](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_include.htm), maybe [apex:composition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_composition.htm). Experiment with joining them up like that as simple html and use renderAs="pdf" when you're happy.